# i have to clone node modesl module to make it work in a class or function

Tags: node.js, freeswitch

i'm writing a nodejs class to play with modesl ( freswitch events module )

```
'use strict';

const esl        = require('modesl');

class eslClass {
    connect() {
        this.fswcon = new esl.Connection(config.fswEslHost, config.fswEslPort, 'ClueCon', () => {
            this._listen();
        });
    }
}
// connect() will failed with a 'this.once' is undefined ( .once is coming from eventEmitter2, i believe )
```

i've to 'clone' object to cancel error

```
const eslClone = esl.Connection;
class eslClass {
    connect() {
        this.fswcon = new eslClone (config.fswEslHost, config.fswEslPort, 'ClueCon', () => {
            this._listen();
        });
    }
}
// error is gone away !!
```

Comment: has you can see, i have a solution, what i'm looking for is an explanation